# How to sum objects and rotate in a for loop?

Tags: python

I have a list of n numbers that I would like to sum over every combination of n-1, storing the output each time.

So, say I have the following:

```
my_scores = []    
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
```

How can I construct a for loop that sums other each combination of three of the four numbers, and stores them in a new list (my_scores)?

Comment: Where are the NumPy objects?

Comment: @Divakar My mistake, what started out as a numpy query ended up being simpler then I originally thought. Thanks for highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Using `combinations` and `sum`:

```
from itertools import combinations
my_scores = [sum(comb) for comb in combinations(mylist, 3)]
my_scores 
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```